# Converting to ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads

I have a consumer/producer program where:

- items to be processed (Strings) go into a BlockingQueue
- I instantiate a fixed number of threads that perform take() from that BlockingQueue and then process those Strings.

The processing threads are instances of this class:

```
class ProcessingThread extends Thread {

    private void process(String s) {
        (big method with calls to other big methods)
    }

    public void run() {
        String s = queue.take();
        process(s);
    }
}
```

Converting to an Executor would be quite straightforward: the Strings would go straight into the Executor, along with a Runnable:

```
class Task implements Runnable {

     private void process(String s) {
        (big method with calls to other big methods)
    }

    public void run() {
         process(s);
     }

}
```

and then:

```
executor.execute(new Task(s));
```

But...every time I instantiate a Task, it would instantiate a very large chunk of code (the processor) - I can't have that, memory requirements would go sky high.

How do I do this?

Comment: "*it would instantiate a very large chunk of code*" => what do you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "instantiate a very large chunk of code"? All instances share the same code. It's not like the byte code of each method is copied every time you instantiate an object.

Comment: I mean that the class ProcessingThread is big, and the resulting Runnable would also be big and expensive to instantiate.

Comment: Don't worry about that yet. Most likely it's not even an issue. I think this is a case of pre-mature optimization. And you are probably talking about measly milliseconds for instanciation.

Comment: I currently have 50 threads handling a million requests per hour. I KNOW I would get an OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: Then you need to allocate your VM heap accordingly. Or scale horizontally and/or vertically if required. But just so you know, instantiating a class multiple times, does not result in multiple copies of said classes bytecode.

Comment: To put some figures into perspective, 1,000,000 requests an hour is not really large today. Its 16,666 a minute. 277 a second. If you have 50 threads, then 20,000 per thread per hour, 333 per thread per minute, and 5 per thread per second. I think you should go with your solution above, profile the application with the workload, and look for any red spots.

Comment: Well, yes and no. I can surely do these things, but to me it's much more elegant to have a way to customize how threads are created by the executor.

Comment: I guess I'm not following. Customize in what way ? The concurrency package in the JDK is huge, and you can do almost anything really: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Comment: Re, "customize how threads are created by the executor."  That's what a `ThreadFactory` is for.  Two of the constructors for the `ThreadPoolExcecutor` class accept a `ThreadFactory` instance as an argument.  Supply your own implementation of `ThreadFactory`, and you will have full control of how the threads are created.

Comment: What you already done is a specialized executor service. Are you sure you want to switch to a standard implementation? What do you want to achieve by that?

Comment: How do you do this? Well to begin with use Runnable. It is the recommended way because it decouples task body from task execution. You are not supposed to extend Thread these days. In fact your thread approach is worse from the memory point of view, as instances of Thread have more variables than instances of Runnable. With Runnables you can have a fixed number of threads.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking Damien O'Reilly advice.

Then you need to allocate your VM heap accordingly. Or scale horizontally and/or vertically if required. But just so you know, instantiating a class multiple times, does not result in multiple copies of said classes bytecode. – Damien O'Reilly Oct 20 at 16:43